how to remove existing js from magento 2.4.6?
I cannot remove exisitng js from magento 2 I made a module which caontains view/frontend/layout folder and in that folder one xml file is there with name default.xml Please help me I want to remove jquery and need to add my own version of jquery file for perticular one page. Is there any solution for this issue ?

Not sure to understand the question perfectly.
In your <head></head> add <remove src="jquery.js"/> and add <script src="js/custom_jquery.js" />?
